# missing save, save and close and cancel button

Tags: content

I have created one user group under public called "Special Author" and in the Global Settings I have assigned right to that group for the Admin login and also a right to create and Edit Own because I want that group of people just to create a content and nothing else (I think, instead of global create and edit own, I should have assigned them  permission into Article component.. I can always do that) but the issue is, when user logs in to create a content, the save, save and close, cancel buttons are missing.. 
Can someone please help me with that? This problem is driving me crazy..

[image: Global Group permission]
[image: Missing Buttons]

Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix an issue.. In case, someone is struggling the same thing. We need to assign the user group to the "Special" ACL. That fixes an issue of Top nav bar and also the save buttons. 
After that I found that JCE editor is not loading for that group of people. Currently I had to enable the TinyMCE and will post once I find a solution to the issue.